# Google Analytics Goals funnels

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

Is Google Analytics Goals funnels only of website tracking?. Actually, i want to implement Google Analytics Goals funnels in android. But regarding this, I'm unable to find any step.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/

Comment: Need Google Analytics Goals funnels screen tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same as for web.

The funnel clearly says "Screen/Page" and the destination says "App screen name or web page URL".

Just make sure that the view is a mobile view and not a web view.